# Contao - How to use font icons (Font-Awesome for example)

Tags: font-awesome, contao

I am using Conta 3.5, and I want to use font icons from

> https://fontawesome.com/

There's a plugin for contao, which add's the option below to the sitelayout menu, but there's a error, whichever option I pick:

```
Query error: Unknown column 'FontAwesome_source' in 'field list' (UPDATE tl_layout SET FontAwesome_source='local' WHERE id='1')
```

Is there another way to bind icons to my contao website or a way to fix that?

Below is an image with the error.

[Contao Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGwgT.png)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can just download the font-awesome CSS file from the website and include it via `<link>`-tag as described [here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself).

Answer (score 0):

It appears you did not open the Contao Install Tool to update the database after installing that extension. It also appears you installed an old version of that extension. The newest version is `4.7.2`, see [here](https://github.com/netzmacht/contao-font-awesome/releases).